# try catch with if null statement

Tags: c#, try-catch

How can I catch an exception around an if statement?

Here is my if statement, and if any of them are null I want to catch an exception

```
try {
      if (user == null || job == null)
} catch() {

}
```

I'm pretty sure this is wrong, does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Apart from the atrocious formatting (consistent indentation!), why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: if job or user is null then throw an exception

Comment: That requirement makes no sense: why throw an exception if you **immediately** catch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
{
   if (user == null || job == null)
   { 
       throw new Exception("user or job is null"); 

   }
}
catch(Exception ex )
{
   //here your code 
}
```

Comment: Kamel You must add Exception parameter

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try with , you can manage custom exception for your treatment

```
try
{
if(condition)
{
 throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
   if (user == null || job == null)
   { 
       throw new Exception("user or job is null"); 

   }
}
catch(Exception $e )
{
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```